# is uboot.bin location-independent?

Tags: boot, u-boot, elf

ubootgenerate uboot.bin and uboot.elf.

- `uboot.bin` is used to burn to flash, at the start address of the CPU.
- `uboot.elf` is not very useful.

**NOTE:** I think `uboot.bin`/`uboot.elf` are all location-independent.

#### Testng

I test as below:

1. From uboot, tftpboot the uboot.elf, then bootelf it. the result is ok.
2. From uboot, tftpboot the uboot.bin, then go it. the result is fail.

   ```
   ZynqMP> tftpboot 0x10000000 192.168.1.6:u-boot.bin
   Using ethernet@ff0c0000 device
   TFTP from server 192.168.1.6; our IP address is 192.168.1.23
   Filename 'u-boot.bin'.
   Load address: 0x10000000
   Loading: ################################################
        4.6 MiB/s
   done
   Bytes transferred = 690200 (a8818 hex)
   ZynqMP> go 0x10000000
   ## Starting application at 0x10000000 ...


   U-Boot 2017.01 (Jul 03 2018 - 22:10:51 -0700) Xilinx ZynqMP ZCU102 revB

   I2C:   ready
   DRAM:  4 GiB----fail at here,like dead.
   ...........
   ```

Does anyone know why?

Answer (score -1):

That's because bin file have load addresses, which can be seen from the output of the `readelf -h u-boot.elf` command.